# Deleting images with javascript function

Tags: php, javascript

In a page, i am showing thumbs of images from a folder, with a link below them "Delete Image",
through this code:

```
echo '<li> <a href="Gallery/'.$file.'" rel="lightbox['.$lightbox.']">';
echo '<div id="image" ><img src="Gallery/thumbs/'.$file.'" alt="" /><br>
<a href="javascript:Del();"><font style="font-size:9px">Delete Image</font>';
echo '</a></div></a></li>';
```

On the Delete Image I am calling a javascript function Del(). I want that if a User clicks on Delete Image, the Image thumb should be deleted, from its containing folder i.e., Gallery/thumbs.

The function Del is:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
function Del(){
    var image_x = document.getElementById('image');
image_x.parentNode.removeChild(image_x);
}
</script>
```

This function removes the images from the page, not from the folder. And also it deletes them like, if i delete on third image it will remove first, then second, in a sequnce.
I want images to be deleted , only those on which user click Delete Image

I hope you all understand.

Comment: You need to use distinct "id" values for every element. That is, it is wrong for more than one element to have the id "image".

Comment: Give every image an id and use ajax to send the id to php to delete from the folder.

Comment: You can't delete an image directly from the client. You need to do it from the server.

Comment: @Adam Ok, how can i do it. I am very new. So please will any body elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use, as it said in the comment AJAX to delete file phisicaly from server. 
I advise you to implement common function for deleting elements from server, from database or files - whatever, cause in general you just need to call some url,
with passed id of the object you want to delete and then - transform DOM elements the way to show that the object is successfully deleted.

```
function remove(el, url, callback) {
    $.post(url, {}, function(response) {
        // Expect that the response would be in JSON format (PHP - json_encode())
        response = $.parseJSON(response);

        // and in reponse JSON there should be the attibute called 'code', which is detects if the deleting where successfull,
        // if it's == 0 that's success, if not - error
        if (response.code == 0) {
            el.remove();

            if (typeof callback == 'function') {
                callback(response);
            } 
        }
    });
}
```

This is the function you need to call server-side delete. To use it put this code, you should also bind trigger on click event on `<a />`
which will initiate deleting this way:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.delete', function(e) {
    // Do not allow browser go to the link's href
    e.preventDefault();

    // pass, as the first element div, which we need to delete from DOM,
    // as the second argument - URL from <a /> to server-side script
    // and third argument is th ecallback function which will remove() function call if the deleting where successfull
    remove($(this).parents('div:first'), $(this).attr('href'), function(r) {
        // here put the extra code to modify DOM after successfull delete
    });
});
```

In the `<a />`'s attribute `href` you should put the link to the server-side script, which will delete the file.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I want to do this using Javascript. Please i m a newbie so give me some more detail